# Use Node.js library from ClojureScript project

Tags: javascript, node.js, clojurescript, figwheel

I'm trying to use a Node.js based component (https://github.com/leandrowd/react-responsive-carousel) in my Figwheel-based ClojureScript app.

Unfortunately I cannot find a "standalone", packaged Javascript file with `react-responsive-carousel`. Since my app is not run by Node.js, it cannot `require` etc.

Is there either an elegant way to reuse Node.js libraries from ClojureScript, or a solution to package any Node.js library into a standalone file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Webpack to turn the library and all its dependencies into a single JavaScript file which exports a reference for the library.
In carousel-module.js

```
global.Carousel = require('react-responsive-carousel').Carousel;
```

Check out the Webpack page for how to set up Webpack.

It's unfortunate that we still have to go through this convoluted method to use CommonJS libraries. I hope native support is coming soon.

Comment: Thank you. I actually used Browserify in a similar way. I second you: it would be so great to be able to do everything from `project.clj`.